# Encapsulate responsiblity of class

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I need some help. Iam implementing user story where when new customer is created, new Account is also created for him. Should the creation of account and assignment of it to property be customer responsibility (creation of account in customer constructor) or should i use some domain service class as some kind of tenant creation processor where the validation logic is also performed?

**Edit:**

When the customer is created, also the customer account is created for him. Customer account does not exists on its own (without customer). But I also need to work with Accounts elswhere in application, should I consider the account as Entity?

I partialy solved is like

```
public class Customer:EntityBase<Customer>
{
   public Customer(...)
   {
      ...
      Account = new Account(this);
   }

   public Account Account {get; private set;}
}

public class Account
{
   public Account(Customer customer)
   {
      if(customer.Account!= null) {throw ...}
      AccountOwner = customer;
   }
   public Customer AccountOwner {get;private set;}
}
```

Comment: Aggregates (and entities within them) are about invariants/behavior. So far, you've described little of that. You seem to be treating these concepts, customer and customer account, as structural things. As Daniel says, you haven't given us much to go on. I advise you to look at CRC cards ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card ) to model more behavior.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need more context in order to give you a good answer. Assuming a Customer will always need an Account (it is only an assumption), then I'd deal with this in the Customer constructor yes. Haven't got a clue how your classes are structured though so this is a guess. It also depends on the relationship between Account and Customer.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on this: does the account have to be destroyed when the customer is destroyed? If it is, then you can create the account in the constructor. If the account "lives" longer then the customer, you have to create it outside of the customer.